# After called popbackstack(),all the added fragments shows up, why?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-lifecycle

I have 3 Fragment A, B, C , in MainActivity.

A ,B,C  extents the BaseFragment:

```
class BaseFragment extents Fragment{
  public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
    super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
    Log.d("onHiddenChanged:",this.getClass().getName()+" hidden:"+hidden);    
    }
    ...
}
```

and In the MainActiviy like that:

```
class MainActiviy extents Activity{
   onCreate(){
     ...
     fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, fragmentA, fragmentA.getClass().getName());
     fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragmentA.getClass().getName());
     fragmentTransaction.commit();

     ...

  }
}
```

When Click fragmentA,just enter to fragmentB （just Add B and Hide A, and add B to BackStack）:

```
fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, fragmentB, fragmentB.getClass().getName());
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragmentB.getClass().getName());
fragmentTransaction.hide(fragmentA).commit();
```

When Click fragmentB,just enter to fragmentC,just like above.

So, I enter A ,enter B ,enter C by step,  and then in the FragmentC, I press the back button,
I notice that, all the added fragment show's up:

```
onHiddenChanged:FragmentB
onHiddenChanged:FragmentA
```

that's not my expects. When I press BackButton in FragnmentC, I just want to show FragmentB, and the FragmentA keep hidden.

Comment: Do you override the `onBackPressed()` method to your MainActivity with : `if(!getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()) super.onBackPressed();` ?

Comment: @Johann67 yes, I use **popBackStackImmediate()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your add all fragments instead of replace.

I would recommend you to use this method instead of add new fragments and hide old ones.

```
private void changeFragment(Fragment frag, boolean saveInBackstack) {
    String backStateName = ((Object) frag).getClass().getName();

    try {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        if (manager.findFragmentByTag(backStateName) == null) {
            //fragment not in back stack, create it.
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, frag, backStateName);

            if (saveInBackstack) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Change Fragment: addToBackTack " + backStateName);
                transaction.addToBackStack(backStateName);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Change Fragment: NO addToBackTack");
            }

            transaction.commit();
        } else {
            manager.popBackStack();
        }
    } catch (IllegalStateException exception) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to commit fragment, could be activity as been killed in
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,But Replace()  method will remove the added Fragments,and some view states will be lost .

Comment: @林凌灵 Yeah. You should store the states on fragments bundle. You can also get some exception too just like "you have already add the fragment". But it is up to you.